# Who exactly were the Dasyus and are they different from the dasa term?

Tags: vedas, arya

As mentioned in previous answer [What are some hymns elaborating and explaining about dasas in rig-veda?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22498/21039) by B.N.Bhaskar, that 'dasa' itself is neutral term and it is not an enemy tribe and 'dasyu' is for a theif/robber so not a tribe.

But according to various foreign historians and even our one of the most emminent historian PV Kane in his book **History of the Dharamshastra** states [here](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.280927/page/n97/mode/2up) the *arya vs dasa* conflict.

So according to the vedas what was this *arya vs dasa* tribal conflict, if there was a conflict at all?

Also in the wikipedia entry [Dasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dasa) it is said that [Sri Aurobindo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Aurobindo) gave metaphysical meaning to this term.

Is there a consensus to this term or is it open to interpretations?

Answer (score 3):

dasyus are defined as people outside varnashrama (irrespective of language they speak) in [manu smriti](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu10.htm) :

> *45. All those tribes in this world, which are excluded from (the community of) those born from the mouth, the arms, the thighs, and the
> feet (of Brahman), are called **Dasyus**, whether they speak the
> language of the Mlecchas (barbarians) or that of the Aryas.*